# asp.net mvc 2 web application inside a Web site?

Tags: iis, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Asp.Net Web Site deployed as a WebSite inside IIS 7.5.

```
http://localhost/WebSite
```

Then I have a second Asp.Net MVC 2 web application which is deployed as Sub Application inside the above WebSite. So the mvc aplication should work on the following Url.

```
http://localhost/WebSite/MvcApp/
```

The web site works fine but when I browse the mvc Url `http://localhost/WebSite/MvcApp/`

It gives following error.

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web
>   server is configured to not list the
>   contents of this directory.

Comment: is the app pool for the MVC application running in classic mode or integrated mode?

Comment: Its in Integrated mode.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing picking up the phone...

IIS is defaulting all the way to checking if directory browsing is turned on. This implies ASP.net is not getting the request at all.

Make sure there is virtual directory setup where folder looks different that regular folders.

Unfortunately I don't do IIS 7.5, still IIS 6.0.

In 6.0 I would right clikc the folder and click Create App. and then goto the last tab and make ure ASP.net was confgured on the folder.

The last possbility is that the ASP.Net routing engine on root is sucking up all the requests for the sub.